# How to use Json variable from output body of one request to another Request body in JMeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter

JMeter Json Request: There are 3 consecutive dependable steps for a target output. I want to use a variable with value from one HTTP output body from  request tab ( not from Response) to another HTTP Request body as a prerequsities variable.

1. I took a HTTP sampler, in SOAP Request few parameter defined as variable where data read from a file (Account Name, Account Number).
2. If pass above Request with proper response like '000' then I want to use that variable data(Account Number, Account Name) to another Request body. But if I get another response ataus except '000' in step-> 1, then I will ignore it for step-2.

Suppose I want read 100 data from the file for 100 threads in step-> 1

Comment: What do you mean ` ignore it for step-2.`? Just don't send request in step2 or use other values instead of `Account Name, Account Number`?

Comment: Please provide some code to reproduce the problem

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, "What do you mean ` ignore it for step-2.": I mean when in step-1 Account Name and Account Number validation will be failed then step-2 will be ignored automatically for that data as Account Name & Account Number should be validated before step-> 2, at the same time Step-> 2 will be executed for valid Account Name and Account Number. It's mentionable that I will test using a couple of Account Numbers from where some are valid and some are invalid data for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If you don't want to run `step-2` at all if the response is not "proper" - put it under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and come up with the condition which checks whether `step-1` was "proper" or not.
2. If you want to run `step-2` but don't want to send `Account Number` and `Account Name` - you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to modify the request body and remove the relevant attributes, see [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) article for more details.